# Ruby gsub doesn't change the content while setting the content does

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, gsub

Could someone please explain the difference between the following two lines of code:

```
1. element.content.gsub!("#{i}", "#{a[i]}")
2. element.content = element.content.gsub("#{i}", "#{a[i]}")
```

In the following code:

```
a.each_index do |i|
  @doc.traverse do |element|
    if element.text?
      element.content = element.content.gsub("#{i}", "#{a[i]}")
    end
  end
end
puts @doc
```

The code as presented above does change @doc. While if I use line 1 with **`gsub!`** it doesn't have an effect on @doc. Does this have to do with how blocks handle their parameters? Shouldn't everything be passed by reference in Ruby unless explicitly copied using a method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html:

```
static VALUE get_content(VALUE self) {
    xmlNodePtr node;
    xmlChar * content;
    Data_Get_Struct(self, xmlNode, node);
    content = xmlNodeGetContent(node);
    if(content) {
        VALUE rval = NOKOGIRI_STR_NEW2(content);
        xmlFree(content);
        return rval;
    }
    return Qnil;
}
```

A copy of the content is made, so any changes to it only affect that copy, and not the internal value of the node's contents.

Using 'element.content=' calls a separate method that does modify the internal value:

```
def content= string
    self.native_content = encode_special_chars(string.to_s)
end
```

Comment: is the method proposed by the OP the right way to make changes  2. element.content = element.content.gsub("#{i}", "#{a[i]}")